# Skip Over Item if element doesn't exist on page

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a script that loops through multiple pages of a website and I want to skip over or add a blank space for the item that might not be on certain pages. For example, there are some pages that do not contain a description about the book. When I run into one of those pages I get an attribute error.  My script below loops through the first two pages with no problem, but when it hits the third page it stops.
Here is the traceback

```
item['description'] = about.h2.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.text File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3.6.egg/bs4/element.py", line 737, in __getattr__ AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How can I fix this? Here is my script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import json

base_url = "https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/"

data = []
n = 30
for i in range(4, n+1):
    response = requests.get(base_url + "BookDetail.aspx?bookId=" + str(i))

    #html parsing
    page_soup = soup(response.content, "html5lib")

    #grabs info for each textbook
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"LongDescription"})
    author = page_soup.select("p")
    about = page_soup.find("div",{"id":"AboutBook"})

    for container in containers:
        item = {}
        item['type'] = "Textbook"
        item['title'] = container.find("div",{"class":"twothird"}).h1.text
        item['author'] = author[3].get_text(separator=', ')
        if item['author'] == " ":
            item['author'] = "University of Minnesota Libraries Publishing"
        item['link'] = "https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/BookDetail.aspx?bookId=" + str(i)
        if not container.find(string="Publisher: "):
            item['publisher_url'] = item['publisher'] = ""
        else:
            item['publisher'] = container.find(text="Publisher: ").nextSibling.text
            item['publisher_url'] = container.find(text="Publisher: ").nextSibling['href']
        item['source'] = "Open Textbook Library"
        if not about.h2.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling:
            item['description'] = ""
        else:
            item['description'] = about.h2.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.text
        item['base_url'] = "https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/"
        if container.find("p",{"class":"Badge-Condition"}).a:
            item['license'] = container.find("p",{"class":"Badge-Condition"}).a.text
        if container.find("img",{"class":"ctl00_maincontent_imgLicence"}):
            item['license'] = ''
        if container.find("p",{"class":"Badge-Condition"}).a:
            item['license_url'] = container.find("p",{"class":"Badge-Condition"}).a["href"]
        if container.find("img",{"class":"ctl00_maincontent_imgLicence"}):
            item['license_url'] = ''
        if container.find("div",{"class":"twothird"}).p:
            item['review'] = container.find("div",{"class":"twothird"}).p.text
        else:
            item['review'] = ''
        if item['review'].startswith('('):
            item['review'] = item['review'].replace('(', '')
        if item['review'].endswith(' reviews)'):
            item['review'] = item['review'].replace(' reviews)', '')
        if item['review'] > str(0):
            item['review'] = "Reviewed Resource"
        else:
            item['review'] = ''
        item['image_url'] = "https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/" + container.img["src"]
        data.append(item) # add the item to the list

    with open("./json/otl-1.json", "w") as writeJSON:
        json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Where does the `AttributeError` happen? Which attribute? Or, better, just post the traceback instead of trying to explain it.

Comment: Also, the issue can't be with `item['description']`. You never try to access that anywhere, only to set it. And, even if you did try to access it, you set it in every control path. And, even if that weren't true, you would get a `KeyError('description')` for that, not an `AttributeError`.

Comment: I just updated my question with the traceback and my full script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend parsing the description with `item['description'] = about.h2.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.text`, that's too much specific. I came up with this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint

base_url = "https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/"

data = []
n = 30
for i in range(4, n+1):
    response = requests.get(base_url + "BookDetail.aspx?bookId=" + str(i))

    page_soup = soup(response.content, "lxml")

    data = {}
    title, author, description =  page_soup.select('h1')[0].text, \
                                  page_soup.select('h1 ~ p')[3].get_text(', '), \
                                  '\n'.join(p.text.strip() for p in page_soup.select('div#AboutBook > p') if p.text.strip())

    data['type'] = "Textbook"
    data['title'] = title
    data['author'] = author if author.strip() else "University of Minnesota Libraries Publishing"
    data['link'] = "https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/BookDetail.aspx?bookId=" + str(i)
    data['source'] = "Open Textbook Library"
    data['description'] = description

    pprint(data)

    # with open("./json/otl-1.json", "w") as writeJSON:
    #     json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Prints:

```
{'author': 'University of Minnesota Libraries Publishing',
 'description': 'This book is intended for an undergraduate or MBA level '
                'Financial Accounting course. It covers the standard topics in '
                'a standard sequence, utilizing the Socratic method of asking '
                'and answering questions.',
 'link': 'https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/BookDetail.aspx?bookId=4',
 'source': 'Open Textbook Library',
 'title': 'Financial Accounting',
 'type': 'Textbook'}

...and so on (for each book)
```

Answer (score -1):

Wherever you are getting the AttributeError you can use the following code:

```
Try:
    your code here
except AttributeError:
    pass or other codes
```